# Insert XML node in the second node, of two identical nodes

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

I am programmatically editing an xml file with XML Starlet. I have the following XML document:

```
    <manifest>
            <application>
                    <activity>
                            <intent-filter>
                                   <action/>
                                   <category/>
                            </intent-filter>
                            <intent-filter>
                            </intent-filter>
                    </activity>
            </application>
    </manifest>
```

I'm trying to add a new `<action>` tag to the second `<intent-filter>` node. How do I do that without creating a node in the first `<intent-filter>` inadvertently?

Expected output:

```
    <manifest>
            <application>
                    <activity>
                            <intent-filter>
                                   <action/>
                                   <category/>
                            </intent-filter>
                            <intent-filter>
                                   <action/>
                            </intent-filter>
                    </activity>
            </application>
    </manifest>
```

I've reviewed the documentation at: http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/xmlstarlet.txt Yet, I appear to be missing the solution for this situation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I was actually having an XPath problem!

```
xml ed -s "(/manifest/application/activity/intent-filter)[2]" -t elem -n action -v "" manifest.xml
```

Although please do chime in if there is another canonical way of achieving this action.